# template0 access privileges and pg_database

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL has 2 template databases: `template0` that can't be modified, and `template1` that is modifiable and is used to create every new database.

So I was playing with *privileges*, granting and revoking, and it caught my attention that, at least in my Docker image (as well as locally installed PostgreSQL), both template database have the same access privileges.

If I read this correct, it is giving connect privilege to both `postgres` default user and `public` role.

```sql
-- output is simplified
postgres=# \l
                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   |   Access privileges
 template0 | postgres | =c/postgres +
                        postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | =c/postgres +
                      | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

Yet I know for sure that trying to connect to *template0* will fail with

> FATAL:  database "template0" is not currently accepting connections.

I did some digging, th catalog `pg_database` has `datallowconn` property and in a description it says

> it is used to protect the template0 database from being altered.

It **might be** an answer, but I'm not sure. I mean it's just a catalog, I think it stores data about object, I'm not sure if it can affect the behaviour of an object in any way.

So the ultimate question is - why can't we connect to `template0`?

Comment: Can you please make your question a little clearer?

Comment: @clemens Can't figure out what prevents me from connecting to `template0`. I look at the access privileges and see that `template0` gives `CONNECT` privilege to default user `postgres`. Moreover, it's access privileges are the same that `template1` has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value `false` in the `datallowconn` field in `pg_database` is the only reason that prevents you from connecting to the `template0` database. You can remove this lock by simply update the value as Postgres super user:

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = TRUE WHERE datname = 'template0';
```

Now, you can connect to `template0` by:

```
psql -Upostgres -dtemplate0
```

But you better not be doing that, of course. The postgres developers will have thought of something when they blocked access. If you corrupt the template databases, it's hard to create a new database.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate an answer.